# Изменения размеров при загрузки изображения!

Tags: php

Знаю есть ответы и примеры в интеренете, но я не могу понять как и что мне брать из моего кода, задача такая, что бы изображение загружаемое на сервер, становилось размерами 200х200 пикселей, вот код:

```
 if(isset($_POST['change_ava']))
    {

        $id_person = $_SESSION['idpersona'];



// Перезапишем переменные для удобства
$filePath  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$errorCode = $_FILES['userfile']['error'];

// Проверим на ошибки
if ($errorCode !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK || !is_uploaded_file($filePath)) {
    // Массив с названиями ошибок
    $errorMessages = [
        UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE   => 'Размер файла превысил значение upload_max_filesize в конфигурации PHP.',
        UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE  => 'Размер загружаемого файла превысил значение MAX_FILE_SIZE в HTML-форме.',
        UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL    => 'Загружаемый файл был получен только частично.',
        UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE    => 'Файл не был загружен.',
        UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => 'Отсутствует временная папка.',
        UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => 'Не удалось записать файл на диск.',
        UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION  => 'PHP-расширение остановило загрузку файла.',
    ];
    // Зададим неизвестную ошибку
    $unknownMessage = 'При загрузке файла произошла неизвестная ошибка.';
    // Если в массиве нет кода ошибки, скажем, что ошибка неизвестна
    $outputMessage = isset($errorMessages[$errorCode]) ? $errorMessages[$errorCode] : $unknownMessage;
    // Выведем название ошибки
    die($outputMessage);
}
// Создадим ресурс FileInfo
$fi = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
// Получим MIME-тип
$mime = (string) finfo_file($fi, $filePath);
// Закроем ресурс
finfo_close($fi);
// Проверим ключевое слово image (image/jpeg, image/png и т. д.)
if (strpos($mime, 'image/jpeg') === false) die('Можно загружать только изображения в формате JPEG.');
// Результат функции запишем в переменную
$image = getimagesize($filePath);
// Зададим ограничения для картинок
$limitBytes  = 1024 * 1024 * 1;
$limitWidth  = 200;
$limitHeight = 200;
// Проверим нужные параметры
if (filesize($filePath) > $limitBytes) die('Размер изображения не должен превышать 1 Мбайт.');
if ($image[1] > $limitHeight)          die('Высота изображения не должна превышать 200 точек.');
if ($image[0] > $limitWidth)           die('Ширина изображения не должна превышать 200 точек.');
// Сгенерируем новое имя файла на основе MD5-хеша
$name = md5_file($filePath);
// Сгенерируем расширение файла на основе типа картинки
$extension = image_type_to_extension($image[2]);
// Сократим .jpeg до .jpg
$format = str_replace('jpeg', 'jpg', $extension);
$rest = substr($id_person, -3); ////////////////////////// Последние 3 цыфры АЙДИШНИКА
$name_format = $name . $rest . $format; 
// Переместим картинку с новым именем и расширением в папку /pics
if (!move_uploaded_file($filePath, __DIR__ . '/avatar/' . $name . $rest . $format)) {
    die('При записи изображения на диск произошла ошибка.');
} else{
    $img_link = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT image FROM user_info WHERE sid = '$id_person'");
    $img_name =  mysqli_fetch_array($img_link);
    $image_l = $img_name['image'];
    $link_del = "avatar/" . $image_l;
    if ($image_l != 'default.jpg')
    {
    unlink($link_del);
    }
    mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `user_info` SET `image` = '$name_format' WHERE `user_info`.`sid` = '$id_person'");
    header('Location: https://win-rate.com/profile');
}
```

Comment: Что у вас не получается? В чём у вас собственно проблема?

Comment: @ArchDemon да собственно, есть скрипт http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=graph&page=014 а как его вставить в мой код не пойму

Comment: Ctrl-C потом Ctrl-V